# Getting the Product object in a custom loop

Tags: plugins

I am currently building a Theme for a site that is using `WooCommerce` to provide a Shop to Customers. I have just started on it, and I am currently working on the Product Category pages. I have hit a road block trying to fetch the WooCommerce Product object.

I have read that using the variable `global $product` should return the WC_Product object, but when I do `the_post(); var_dump($product)`, `NULL` is returned.

I tried to then create a Product object by doing `the_post(); $product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID())`, but when I did the `var_dump($product)` on that, it gave me general information about the product (`post_name`, `post_description`, etc), but nothing further than if I called `get_post()`.

Can someone tell me what I have missed please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I have almost instantly found the solution. Thought about deleting the question, but in case others have the same problem, I will leave it here.

To get the Product object with all the required attributes, you need to call `get_product()` after `the_post()`, and that will return the Product object for you to use.

Comment: `get_product()` is deprecated `wc_get_product()` should replace it... Anyway it is **just a shorthand** for: `WC()->product_factory->get_product( $the_product, $args )`

Answer (score 3):

You could use a custom query to fetch the product object. Here is a snippet to get the stock count. Take a look at the product class: http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html for functions available for the product object.

```
<?php $args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'product',
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'    => -1,
            'orderby'           => 'title',
            'order'             => 'ASC',               
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'  => 'product_type',
                    'field'     => 'slug',
                    'terms'     => array('simple'),
                    'operator'  => 'IN'
                )
            )
        );

        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        $stock_count = array();
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                        global $product;
                        $stock_count[] = $product->get_stock_quantity();

        endwhile; 


        // count the array values and output them
        echo "<h2>Stock Count: ".array_sum($stock_count)."</h2>";
        ?>
```